Interval [0;1] is divided into 2*n sub-intervals, each smaller than ½, find two intervals with index difference n, containing points with distance ½
Given division of interval $[0;1]$ into $2n$ consecutive sub-intervals of nonzero length, each smaller than $\frac12$ in length, $I_{1}, …, I_{2n}$, we can always find a pair of intervals with index difference $n$ (like $I_1$ and $I_{n+1}$), such,that they contain in their inner parts two points at distance $\frac12.$

Don't try to fit the whole question in the title - it leads to bad MathJax compromises, and the goal of the title should be to quickly give a reader an idea of whether they can help you or not.

agree! but still tempting...

Here's a proof sketch.  Feel free to fill in the details, but all the tools you need are introduced here.
For each interval $I$, define $F(I) = [\inf I, \sup I)$.  For instance, $F((a,b]) = [a,b)$.  Here, we note that

the interior of $I_i$ is the same as the interior of $F(I_i)$.
$F(I_1), F(I_2),\ldots, F(I_{2n})$ are nonempty intervals which partition $[0,1)$
If $i\neq j$ and $x \in F(I_i), y \in F(I_j)$, then $x < y \iff i < j$.

Define the function $\varphi : [0,1) \to \{1,2,\ldots, 2n\}$ by $\varphi(x) = i \iff x \in F(I_i)$.  (equivalently, $x \in F(I_{\varphi(x)})$)
Then define the function $g : [0,1/2) \to \mathbb{Z}$ by $g(x) = \varphi(x+1/2) - \varphi(x) - n$.
The function $g$ satisfies three properties:

$g(0) + \lim_{x\to 1/2^-} g(x) \in \{0,-1\}$
For any $x\in [0,1/2)$, $\left|g(x) - \lim_{y\to x^-} g(y)\right| \leq 1$.
For any $x\in [0,1/2)$, $\lim_{y\to x^+} g(y) = g(x)$.

By the third bullet point, it suffices to show $g$ has some zero (rather than a zero in the interiors of the intervals).  By the first bullet point, either $g(0) = 0$ or $\lim_{x\to1/2^-}g(x)=0$ or $g$ changes signs somewhere in $[0,1/2)$.  By the second bullet point, $g$ cannot skip an integer.
As a result, $g$ has a zero, so we're finished.

OK Thanks! I see that this Lemma statement is surely correct...

Let's denote $I_i = [b_i, e_i]$ and the "image" of that interval $Im(I_i) = [b_i + \frac{1}{2}, e_i + \frac{1}{2}]$ (this is the set off all points that differ by $\frac{1}{2}$ from the points of $I_i$).
Let's observe at first, that there is some interval, that contains number $\frac{1}{2}$. By symmetry we can asssume that it happens for some interval $I_j$, where $j \leqslant n$. We can see that $1 \in Im(I_j)$ so $Im(I_j) \cap I_{2n} \neq \varnothing$. Consider now the least index (let's say $k$) for which we have $Im(I_j) \cap I_k \neq \varnothing$.
Now if $k \leqslant j + n$ then we are done, because this tells us that $Im(I_j) \cap I_{j+n} \neq \varnothing$, so there are two numbers that differ by $\frac{1}{2}$ in sets $I_j$ and $I_{j + n}$.
If not, then we can observe that either $Im(I_{j-1}) \cap I_k \neq \varnothing$ or if $Im(I_{j-1}) \cap I_k = \varnothing$ then $Im(I_{j-1}) \cap I_{k-1} \neq \varnothing$ but then we have also $k - 1 > j - 1 + n$. Thus we can repeat the reasoning for the index $j - 1$ and so on. We will eventually find some index (for convenience called $j$) for which $k$ (defined as above) satisfies $k \leqslant j + n$, beacuse eventually we have $Im(I_1) \cap I_j  \neq \varnothing$ and $j < n + 1$.
Note We don't necessarily need the intervals of the form $[a,b]$ they can also be for example $[a,b)$ etc., since we just use the fact that their sum fully covers the interval $[0,1]$.

interval contains number 1/2 - you mean inside or it can be border point? as inventor of this lengthy proof above that i am comfortable with, i am worried about such minor things, maybe yours is also correct, didn't have time to get deeper into it

This can be border point but must belong to the interval

OK, thanks! just wanted to make sure you treated my "in their inner parts" correctly, I need this all for other topic where it matters

We define following function $f(x)$ on interval $(0;1)$:
$$(0)f(x) = x + 1/2, x < 1/2; f(x) = x - 1/2, x > 1/2; f(x) = 1/2, x = 1/2$$
Let $B$ be a set of all bordering points $B^1, … , B^{2n-1}$ between $2*n$ intervals. Let $L^{min}$ be a minimal length of these $2*n$ intervals.
Let $N(x)$ be a function equal to an index of interval to which x belongs, defined for all $x$, belonging to inner parts of $2*n$ intervals.
We find in inner parts of $2*n$ intervals $2*n$ points, one point for each interval, which we call $BeginInt^1, …, BeginInt^{2n}$ , based on following rules (we can always do so because number of intervals is finite and their lengths are not zero, if some rule for $BeginInt^j$ is not satisfied we divide by 2 distance  $BeginInt^j - B^{ j-1}$ until it satisfies all rules):
$$(1) BeginInt^j ≠ ½$$
$$(2) BeginInt^j - B^{ j-1} < L{ min} / 2 ; j > 1$$
$$(3) BeginInt^1 < L{ min} / 2$$
$$(4) f( BeginInt^j ) ∉ B $$
$$(5) ∀ x: x ⊂ (B{ j-1}; BeginInt^j) ⇨ N( f( x ) ) = N( f(BeginInt^j) )  ; j > 1$$
$$(6) ∀ x: x ⊂ (0; BeginInt^1) ⇨ N( f( x ) ) = N( f(BeginInt^1) )   $$
We find in inner parts of $2*n$ intervals $2*n$ points, one point for each interval, which we call $EndInt^1, …, EndInt^{2n} $, based on following rules (we can always do so because number of intervals is finite and their lengths are not zero, if some rule for $EndInt^j$ is not satisfied we divide by 2 distance  $B^j - EndInt^j$ until it satisfies all rules):
$$(7) EndInt^j ≠ ½$$
$$(8) B^j - EndInt^j < L^{ min} / 2 ; j < 2*n$$
$$(9) 1 - EndInt^{ 2n } < L^{ min} / 2$$
$$(10)  f( EndInt^j ) ∉ B $$
$$(11)  ∀ x: x ⊂ (EndInt^j; B^j) ⇨ N( f( x ) ) = N( f(EndInt^j) )  ; j < 2*n$$
$$(12)  ∀ x: x ⊂ (EndInt^{ 2n};1) ⇨ N( f( x ) ) = N( f(EndInt^{ 2n}) )  $$
Assume that Lemma is false. If $f(BeginInt^1) ∈ Int^{ n+1} $ our Lemma’s statement is fulfilled, so this cannot be the case. Let’s assume that $f(BeginInt^1) ∈ Int^{ n+2 } ∪ … ∪ Int^{ 2n }$, it follows that $∀j, 1 < j ≤ n: f(BeginInt^j) ∈ Int^{ n+2 } ∪ … ∪ Int^{ 2n }$, because, if contrarily, we have for some $1 < j ≤ n: f(BeginInt^j) ∈ Int^1 ∪ … ∪ Int^{ n+1} $, we cannot have $f(BeginInt^j) < BeginInt^1$, as it would mean that we could chose smaller $BeginInt^1$, which satisfies $f(BeginInt^1) = BeginInt^j , j ≤ n$ (here contradiction with (6)), it is also not possible to have $f(BeginInt^j) = Begin_Int^1$, as we have $j ≤ n, f(BeginInt^1) ∈ Int^{ n+2 } ∪ … ∪ Int^{ 2n } $, and finally, we cannot have $f(BeginInt^j) > BeginInt^1$, as it would mean that we have two intervals, one inside another, namely $( f(BeginInt^j) ; BeginInt^j ) ⊂ ( BeginInt^1 ; f(BeginInt^1) )$, they are not the same, because $f(BegiInt^j) ≠ BeginInt^1$, and both have length ½ because of definition of $f(x)$.
Knowing that $∀ j, 1 < j ≤ n: f(BeginInt^j) ∈ Int^{ n+2 } ∪ … ∪ Int^{ 2n }$, we can say that $f(BegiInt^1) < f(Begin_Int^2) <  … <  f(BeginInt^n)$ due to definition of $f(x)$.
If $∀ j, 1 < j ≤ n: f(BeginInt^j) ∈ Int^{ n+2  } ∪ … ∪ Int^{ 2n }$, we also have $∀ j, 2 ≤ j ≤ n: f(BeginInt^j) ∈ Int^{ n+2 } ∪ … ∪ Int^{ 2n }$, it means that we know that the next statement:
$$(13) ∀ m ≤ j ≤ n: f(BeginInt^j) ∈ Int^{ n+m } ∪ … ∪ Int^{ 2n } $$
is true for $m = 2$, this is our base case in induction on $m$, and we aim to prove the above statement (13) for all $m$ up to $n$. It is easy to see that if $∀ j, m ≤ j ≤ n: f(BeginInt^j) ∈ Int^{ n+m } ∪ … ∪ Int^{ 2n }$, because $f(BeginInt^m) ∉ Int^{ n+m } $ (otherwise our Lemma’s statement is fulfilled), and because $f(BeginInt^1) < f(BeginInt^2) <  … <  f(BeginInt^n)$,  it follows that $∀ j, m+1 ≤ j ≤ n: f(BeginInt^j) ∈ Int^{ n+m+1  } ∪ … ∪ Int^{ 2n }$, and we proved by induction that $f(BeginInt^n) ∈ Int^{ 2n }$, which is the statement of our Lemma. This means that our assumption that $f(BeginInt^1) ∈ Int^{ n+2 } ∪ … ∪ Int^{ 2n }$ is wrong, and we are left with the only possibility that $f(BeginInt^1) ∈ Int^2 ∪ … ∪ Int^n$. Consider $f(EndInt^{ 2n })$, we can show that $f(EndInt^{ 2n }) ∈ Int^1 ∪ … ∪ Int^n$, otherwise we will have $EndInt^{ 2n } - f(EndInt^{ 2n })  = ½$ and $f(EndInt^{ 2n })  - f(BeginInt^1) > ½$ at the same time, which is not possible because all these points belong to interval $(0;1)$. Starting from here the proof for the last case will be the same as it was for already proven case (when $f(BeginInt^1) ∈ Int^{ n+2 } ∪ … ∪ Int^{ 2n }$), we just need to change $BeginInt^…$ for $EndInt^…$ and point on symmetry of the function $f(x)$ and rules (1) – (12) with respect to the middle point of interval $(0;1)$. Following the same steps as above we are coming to a contradiction, showing that $f(EndInt^n) ∈ Int^1$. This completes Lemma’s proof.

Multi-letter variables makes math so much harder to read.

I will think about it, of course it doesn't change the meaning
